# Will this code from Android SDK sample cause a memory leak of the parent Activity?

Tags: android

So from reading/research about memory leaks it suggests to make all inner classes static to avoid memory leaks.  However, by looking at the SDK samples (specifically TicTacToeLib) they implement their callbacks without the use of static inner classes. Will this cause a memory leak? If not, why?

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(new MyHandlerCallback());


private class MyHandlerCallback implements Callback {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == MSG_COMPUTER_TURN) {

                // Pick a non-used cell at random. That's about all the AI you need for this game.
                State[] data = mGameView.getData();
                int used = 0;
                while (used != 0x1F) {
                    int index = mRnd.nextInt(9);
                    if (((used >> index) & 1) == 0) {
                        used |= 1 << index;
                        if (data[index] == State.EMPTY) {
                            mGameView.setCell(index, mGameView.getCurrentPlayer());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                finishTurn();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that marking a class as non-static will create a memory leak?

Comment: Non static inner classes will hold references to the parent class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this sample will cause a leak in case it keeps a `Message` in the queue. But it's not a very severe leak since it is usually limited to a rather short amount of time.

But there is a rather simple way to prevent the leak:

Put the following two classes into your project

```
/** Callback that decouples the wrapped Callback via WeakReference */
public class SafeCallback implements Handler.Callback {
    private final WeakReference<Handler.Callback> mCallback;
    public SafeCallback(Handler.Callback callback) {
        mCallback = new WeakReference<Handler.Callback>(callback);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Handler.Callback callback = mCallback.get();
        if (callback != null)
            return callback.handleMessage(msg);
        // else warn, return true, ..?
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
/** replacement for anonymous inner Handler implementations */
public abstract class SafeHandler implements Handler.Callback {
    @Override
    public abstract boolean handleMessage(Message msg);

    public final Handler get() {
        return new Handler(new SafeCallback(this));
    }
    public final Handler get(Looper looper) {
        return new Handler(looper, new SafeCallback(this));
    }
}
```

And now you can use `Handler` / `Callback` almost as you used to do but it's no longer leaking.

So either like

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new SafeHandler() { // << instead of new Handler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // handle message
                return false;
            }
        }.get(); // << Notice this added .get()
    }
}
```

or like

```
public class TestActivity2 extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new Handler(new SafeCallback(this)); // << wrapped in SafeCallback
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // handle message
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The leak problem with `Handler` is that each `Message` / `Runnable` (which is actually wrapped in a `Message`) knows it's target, i.e. has a hard reference to the `Handler` or `Callback`. And if that target is a non-static inner class, it will have an implicit hard reference to the outer class which is typically an `Activity`.

That means that as long as there are `Messages` enqueued for your `Handler`, your whole `Activity` can't be garbage collected.

To solve this issue that chain of hard references from `Message` to `Activity` has to be broken. The `SafeCallback` class does exactly that by keeping just a `WeakReference` towards your `Activity`.

That means, the `Message` has now a hard reference to `SafeCallback` but the part bind there can now be garbage collected. In case that happens `Handler.Callback callback = mCallback.get();` will turn out `null` and the `Message` is simply discarded. There is no more useful target anyways. It is still leaking the `SafeCallback` itself but that's a pretty much empty class so it won't lead to problems.

Answer (score -1):

I would approach it from the standpoint of what use case are you trying to solve, and not what the language itself is doing.  If you "nested class" (not inner class because inner classes can't be static) needs to be able to call non-static methods on its parent class, or read non-static members, then you don't have much choice but to make it non-static.  If you can get away with not accessing any of the parent class's non-static resources, then by all means do so (you'll save some memory that way anyways).  However, if you're worried about memory leaks and you're going to make the nested class private as in your example, then you really shouldn't have anything to worry about because instances of that class can only be created locally to the parent class (unless you create a static member of the parent class that holds a reference to an instance of the nested class, in which case that object would be around until the parent class gets unloaded by the VM).
In summary, I wouldn't personally worry too much about whether or not your nested class is declared as static or non-static, but focus more on the lifecycle of instances of that class, if you're worried about leaking memory.